# Ubuntu + Win 7 dual boot -> Common Partition suffers data loss

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, ntfs

Hi I installed Win 7 (~108GB NTFS), and then added Ubuntu 16.04 64bit (~34GB ext4 + 6GB swap) on my 250GB SSD, and left around **90GB (NTFS) - D drive** in a **common partition** where I wanted to keep my data.

Now there have been some issues starting with:

1. A folder in D that I renamed in Ubuntu didn't get renamed in windows till I booted again into both OSes.
2. My external HDD (NTFS) occasionally started suffering stuck videos that'd stay stuck in my Win too until I diskchkd and repaired it.
3. **This is where it gets serious.**

   a. A folder I totally modified in Linux (ran script to compress jpegs, sorted, copied them) seemed to look as it was before the modifications in Windows. (perhaps because I'd only sent deleted stuff to the trash)

   b. On returning to Ubuntu, emptying the trash and then booting to Windows, windows ran a preboot diskcheck and deleted some stuff, and then I only saw remnants of the original files, and no newly created files.

   c. Alarmed, I returned to Ubuntu, and those files disappeared from there too, and there was a new folder **Found**, where they (and also my complete dropbox folder) seemed to have migrated too, losing their rather complex folder structure.

This is rather problematic, if I have to repair it myself, and needs a change to be sustainable. What am I doing wrong, and what should I do now?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Also, on restoring from hibernate I keep getting the message that my dropbox folder is missing (Please exit or relink.), since D takes a while to mount. Dunno if they're related.

Comment: Also, sometimes it'd take ages for a folder to be moved to a parent folder, instead of instantaneously. It was instantaneous in the terminal though.

Comment: This is related to a faulty/broken NTFS partition and has little to do with Ubuntu. You're better off making a copy on an external drive, formatting the partition and putting back all the files in there.

Comment: How to know if it's due to a problem in the NTFS partition? It's a new recently formatted drive.

Comment: «there was a new folder Found, where they (and also my complete dropbox folder) seemed to have migrated too, losing their rather complex folder structure» ← This seems a classic description of NTFS inconsistencies / problems.

Comment: Apparently, as someone on reddit pointed out, one of the possible reasons could be hibernating on both Windows and Ubuntu, where both use D drive. 

The problem seems to have been less recurrent since I stopped doing that.

Comment: If you solved the problem, please write a self answer and provide the link for reference as well. :)

Comment: Actually I'm not sure it's a solution, as I still get the same issue. 

Although what's weird is that this whole thing is really sporadic. Sometimes it wouldn't happen even if I write to the shared partition, while sometimes it does. 

However I had to face it a few days ago after like 3 weeks. 

Also I read about not hibernating while using a shared partition at a few places, so I thought I'd share this useful info here.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't necessarily the right answer, but it has useful details that might help others, and seems the best thing that worked a fair bit so far.

As someone on reddit pointed out, one possible reason for this deletion was hibernating on one OS while the other boots, thus using (and likely writing to) the shared drive that the first OS has some image of.

Ever since I've stopped doing this, the problem has recurred far less frequently, and the times it did recur, I may actually have hibernated Windows by mistake (it's muscle memory).

This may actually be the right answer, but I'd need more verification to aver that.

Comment: One more thing. It fails to boot when there's an external HDD connected too.

As usual it gets stuck on the loading screen where Win & has those animated window panes flying around and coming together to form the windows logo. Whenever it fails to boot... this doesn't happen.

Comment: **THE ACTUAL REASON >>** Not that anyone cares, but it's the external HDD that causes it. Possibly only HDDs that don't have a space in their name, or only seagate HDDs. My WDD 'My Passport' doesn't cause the same issue.